# Ionic tabs, icons dont show up when using icon-on / icon-off

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, sass

i have the following tab:

```
<ion-tab [root]="HomeTab" tabTitle="Home" icon-off="customicon" icon-on="customicon-outline"></ion-tab>
```

The idea is that whenthe tab is selected, it shows me a icon and when not, it shows me another.

However, when i use icon-off / icon-on, the icon doesnt even appear.

But using `tabIcon="customicon"` works.

What is my mistake?

tab.html:

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="HomeTab" tabTitle="Home" icon-off="customicon" icon-on="customicon-outline"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="RecentTab" tabTitle="Letzte"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="FavTab" tabTitle="Favoriten"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="PersonalTab" tabTitle="Mein"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="InfoTab" tabTitle="Info"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

tab.scss:

```
.ion-ios-customicon,
.ion-md-customicon {
  content: url(../../assets/fonts/Homeblau.svg);
  width: 24px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.ion-ios-customicon-outline,
.ion-md-customicon-outline {
  content: url(../../assets/fonts/Homegrau.svg);
  width: 24px;
  height: 32px;
  padding: 6px 4px 2px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom icon please use following code

**tab.html**

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="HomeTab" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon={{homeIcon}}></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**tab.ts**

set value of `homeIcon` as per your requirement

```
this.homeIcon = 'custome-home-on-icon' // < -- here you can put your condition
```

**app.csss**

```
ion-icon {
    &[class*="custome-"] {
        // Instead of using the font-based icons
        // We're applying SVG masks
        mask-size: contain;
        mask-position: 50% 50%;
        mask-repeat: no-repeat;
        background: 'black';
        width: 1em;
        height: 1em;
    }
    // custom icons
    &[class*="custome-home-on-icon"] {
        mask-image: url('../assets/fonts/Homegrau.svg');
    }
    &[class*="custome-home-off-icon"] {
        mask-image: url('../assets/fonts/Homeblau.svg');
    }
}
```

i hope its work for you...